# Extract all but the last word + the last word

Tags: regex

Using `Regex` POSIX. Given a sentence, how can I extract all but the last word + the last word (preferably without the space between "to" and "2")? In my case, the last word will always be a number.

E.g.:
The string: `Let's count from 1 to 2` is split into `Let's count from 1 to` and `2`

Comment: 2 is not a word !? It's a number

Comment: [How about this](http://regex101.com/r/uS3aM3/1)? `(.*)([\d]+)$`

Comment: Yes. `\d` vs `\w`. Same problem...

Comment: @JamesThorpe, is that the best solution? Considering backtracking.

Comment: @l33t It's _a_ solution... missed the bit about not capturing the space: `(.*) ([\d]+)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your last word will always be a digit:

```
/^([\S ]+) (\d+)$/
```

- Starting at the beginning
- All word characters and spaces (1 or more times)
- Don't grab the space before the last word
- All digits (1 or more times)
- End of the line/string

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
/(.*?)\s+(\w+)$/
```

Check http://regex101.com/r/zK3iQ2/1

Comment: I'm not sure the lazy cardinality is necessary here, thanks to the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex.

```
^(.+)\s(\d+)$
```